# datatable being cleared between page loads ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to append to an already existing datatable, that is then bound to a gridview, using the following code.

```
        int connectpointIndex = compressorsTable.Rows.Count;

        connectpointTable.Rows.Add();            

        int i = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < connectpointColumnNames.Length; i++)
        {
            //connectpointOutput is an array containing the data i want to add to the table
            connectpointTable.Rows[connectpointIndex][connectpointColumnNames[i]] = connectpointOutput[0, i];                                
        }

        assignedSensors.DataSource = connectpointTable;
        assignedSensors.DataBind();
```

I know the table has data in it but connectpointIndex is returning 0, so the first row is overwritten instead of being added to the end.

has this got something to do with page loads?

Im very new to asp.net and would appreciate any help given.

Comment: Highly recommend you read this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.90%29.aspx and this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx

Comment: What is the data type of compressorsTable? Is it a DataTable? How are getting the data into it and how are you sending it back to the database?

Comment: @Erik, I am reading from a database, placing this data in the dataTable (connectpointTable) then binding this to the gridview.

another table next to this displays the "connectpoints" that can be added, when the user clicks one to be added, that is when i want to add it to this datatable/gridview